# Showing NaN for pandas column AD

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to get data to show `NaN` for pandas column AD

My data looks like:

df1

```
    EW   WE   DA   AA  DDA
0   CA   DA  DFA  DAW  DAQ
1   CA   DA  DFA  DAW  DAQ
2   CA   DA  DFA  DAW  DAQ
3    d  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

df2

```
    AA   AB  AC   AD   AE
0  HAC   aw   d  1.0   xa
1  HAC   aw  aw  1.0   xa
2  HAC   aw  aw  1.0   xa
3  HAC   aw  aw  1.0   xa
4  HAC   aw  aw  1.0   xa
5  HAC   aw  aw  1.0   xa
6  NaN  NaN   d  NaN  NaN
```

I want:

```
    AA   AB  AC   AD   AE
0  HAC   aw   d  1.0   xa
1  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
2  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
3  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
4  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
5  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
6  NaN  NaN   d  1.0  NaN
```

I am using:

```
df3 = df2[df2.AC.isin(df1.EW)]
df3 = df3[['AC','AD']]
print (df3)
```

Comment: @jezrael Good catch.  Let me correct that now

Comment: OOPs sorry, there is no last 1, becaus not in `df2` as last value in `AD` column, right?

Comment: @jezrael I'm trying to get values beside d where d is present in both dataframes.

Comment: Yes, I understandm but it seems there is no last 1, because last value of `AD` in `df2` is `NaN`. So I guess last value should be `1`, no `NaN` in `df2`, so then output  will be OK.

Comment: @jezrael Uh yeah,  true that,  The solution for me is giving all blanks (NaN) for AD.

Comment: What return `print (mask)` ? there are some `True`s ?

Comment: @jezrael There is a True for 6

Comment: Yes, but there is no change, because last value is `NaN`. And if no True in first value it means there is some problem with `d` in `AC` in first value of with `d` in `EW`, because no match...

Comment: If some trailing ACthen need `df1['EW'] = df1['EW'].str.strip()` and `df2['AC'] = df2['EW'].str.strip()`.

Comment: @jezrael Adding that made everything true.

Comment: It means in column `EW` is at least one value `aw`.

Comment: @jezrael I tried it with an excel file v csv file and still same issue.  Hmmz

Comment: What issue? All `True`s? Or no match?

Comment: @jezrael Wait nevermind, no issue.  I think Excel seems a bit more reliable.  Also is it normal to be able to read from an excel file/csv while its open.  I feel like that will cause corruption issues, or at least with csv it does.  Excel seems to work more consistently or is that just me.

Comment: Yes, it seems some data issue.

Comment: @jezrael Column AC appears wrong actually.  It  appears as all NaN except the d.

Comment: And mask? It return `True`s correctly?

Comment: @jezrael I get one d which is wanted.   All false for mask except for 6 so it seems ok

Comment: @jezrael I don't suppose you'd be able to help with a script I have?  I'm still struggling a bit with vlookups with Pandas.

Comment: I am offline now :( On phone only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mask = df2.AC.isin(df1.EW)
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
Name: AC, dtype: bool

df3 = df2.copy()
df3['AD'] = np.where(mask, df3['AD'], np.nan)
print (df3)
    AA   AB  AC   AD   AE
0  HAC   aw   d  1.0   xa
1  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
2  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
3  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
4  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
5  HAC   aw  aw  NaN   xa
6  NaN  NaN   d  NaN  NaN
```